# Getting a syntax error from Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python

If you go to the site https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter1/, it tells you to enter the code `>>>2+3*6` into the mu editor, on python 3 mode. I keep getting the error:

```
 File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\mu editor\training.py", line 1
    >>>2+3*6
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell, it is entered exactly as instructed.

Comment: Trying to close this as “Not reproducible or was caused by a typo” is unkind and unhelpful. A complete beginner doesn’t know which part is a typo, and a web search for `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is unlikely to help.

Comment: In your code editor jusst type **2+3*6**. Don't write like **>>>2+3*6**. You can write like this ```calculate= 2+3*6```. Then print the calculate variable `print(calculate)`

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: This was introduced _in the material_: _"You should see a >>> prompt in the interactive shell. Enter 2 + 2 at the prompt..."_

Answer (score 1):

The `>>>` part is called the “prompt”. **You don’t type `>>>`.** The Python interpreter prints the prompt to tell you that it’s ready for you to type some Python code. You just type the `2+3*6` part and press the “return” or “enter” key.